# How to test if array contains at least one element

Tags: php

How should I test if an array contains at least 1 element (rather than just being an empty array `$myarray = array();`)?

Is there a THE way?

E.g.

```
if ($myarray) { }

if (count($myarray)) { }

if (count($myarray) > 0) { }
```

Or is there a THE wrong way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For at least 1 element it would be:

```
if (!empty($myarray)) {}
```

Comment: It returns true if the array contains at least 1 item.

Comment: Thanks! it's so simple but useful.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe check for *non*-emptiness via [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/function.empty.php)?

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - **array() (an empty array)**
> - var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

```
if (!empty($myarray)) { 
    //
}
```

But I am not sure, if there is one canonical way to do it; php might follow [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

Comment: @miku Well it's propably a matter of `TIMTOWTDIBSCINABTE` so `empty()` it is :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe `if(!empty($myarray))` works too. It will mean you won't run w/e if you get `array([0] => '')`

Comment: What do you mean by `It will mean you won't run w/e if you get array([0] => '')`?

Comment: For those finding this now, `empty()` does not check the first index of an array for a truthy value. If an array has a key, even with a falsey value, it will return truthy and not empty.